# Does adding meta tags in a GitHub README make it more searchable

Tags: github, seo, meta-tags

If I use `<meta>` tags like keywords and description in a GitHub README.md file will it make the repo more SEO friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of ([GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) should be able to confirm or refute it).

Even projects about meta and SEO ([seo_meta](https://github.com/parndt/seo_meta), [meta-tags](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags), ...) don't add `<meta>` in their `README.md`.
You find them mentioned in [this documentation](https://github.com/forkcms/documentation/blob/master/module%20guide/meta_data_and_seo.md), but it is for a separate CMS: [forkcms](https://github.com/forkcms/forkcms) (nothing to do with GitHub pages).

Answer (score 3):

Browser engine doesn't need any meta tags to works. @n1trux recommand me to use this for [awesome-regex](https://github.com/aloisdg/awesome-regex) :

```
<!--
  Title: Awesome Regex
  Description: A curated list of amazingly awesome regex resources.
  Author: aloisdg
  -->
```

You can see it on the [raw README.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aloisdg/awesome-regex/master/README.md).

@n1trux full message :

> In my awesome-sysadmin repo, I did it like this:

```
<!--
  Title: Awesome Sysadmin
  Description: A curated list of amazingly awesome open source sysadmin resources.
  Author: n1trux
  -->
```

> Which is essentially an HTML comment. You could also just use real meta tags like so:

```
<meta name='keywords' content='regex, regular expressions, regexp'>
```

> If you include that in the header, it won't be shown.

[source](https://github.com/aloisdg/awesome-regex/issues/9)